# res.json NodeJS/ Express

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, express.js

Estou com uma duvida cruel no nodeJs/ Express, sou bem novo na linguagem mas o que preciso é passar o id em uma rota para que execute e retorne uma query.

Estou querendo fazer em arquivos fragmentados, portanto tenho um arquivo Routes(com todas as rotas) um arquivo API (onde solicita as queries) e um arquivo Database (onde executa e retorna tudo) o código está abaixo :

Routes:

```
const express= require('express')

module.exports = function (server) {

  const router = express.Router()
  server.use('/api',router)

  const taskList = require('../api/taskList/taskList')
  router.route('/taskList').get(taskList.getTaskList)

  router.get('/taskList/:id?',(req,res) =>{
    if(req.params.id) id = parseInt(req.params.id)
    return taskList.getTaskListById(id)
  })


}
```

API:

```
const con = require('../../config/database')

//console.log(con.connectionCheck())
function getTaskList(req,res){
  return con.query('SELECT * FROM TB_TASKLIST',res)
}

function getTaskListById(id,res){
  //return console.log(id)
    return con.queryById(`SELECT * FROM TB_TASKLIST WHERE COD_ID_USER_TASK_LIST like ${id}`,res)
    console.log(res)
}

module.exports = {getTaskList,getTaskListById}
```

Database:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  user:'root',
  password:'',
  database:'db_lifeapp'
})


function connectionCheck(){
  connection.connect(function(err) {
    if(err) console.log(err)
    console.log("conectado")
  })
}

function query(sqlQry,res){
  connection.query(sqlQry,function (err,results,fields) {
    if(err){
      res.json(err)
    }else{
      res.json(results)
      console.log("Query Executada")
    }
  })
}

function queryById(sqlQry,res){
  connection.query(sqlQry,function (err,results,fields) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
    }else{
      console.log("executado")
      res.json(results)
    }
  })
}

module.exports = {connectionCheck,query,queryById}
```

A primeira query onde não passo id executa sem erro, inclusive já testei e o ID está sendo passado, por exemplo se eu der um `console.log(results)` no arquivo database ele me loga a query. 
Meu problema está sendo mandar isso pro navegador, pois quando coloco `res.json(results)` ele da erro :

```
C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\config\database.js:35:10)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\felipe.sangiorge\Desktop\ProjetoAPP\Backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda Obrigado!

Comment: Sempre que chamas `taskList.getTaskListById(id)` tens de passar o `res`. Eu acho que não devias passar o `res` assim para outras funções. É melhor o `res` ser chamado com o resultado da base de dados no modulo onde chamas `taskList`. Senão fica difícil seguir a lógica da aplicação a meu ver.

Comment: Cara não acredito que era algo tão bobo assim HUAUAUHAHUAUH serio kkkkkkkkkkk eu quebrei cabeça o dia todo pra arrumar isso, mas valeu de mais, mas a ideia é só segmentar mesmo virão mais APIs então essa separação vai ser util, muito obrigado cara posta ai pra eu marcar como certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre que chamas `taskList.getTaskListById(id)` tens de passar o `res`.

Mas eu acho que não devias passar o `res` assim para outras funções. É melhor o `res` ser chamado com o resultado da base de dados no modulo onde chamas `taskList`. Senão fica difícil seguir a lógica da aplicação a meu ver.

Por exemplo:

```
router.get('/taskList/:id?', (req, res) =>{
    if(req.params.id) id = parseInt(req.params.id)
    taskList.getTaskListById(id).then(data => res.json(data));
})
```

e a API ser:

```
function query(sqlQry, res) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.query(sqlQry, function(err, results, fields) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(results);
        });
    });
}
```